# RPN to infix with both numbers and pronumerals in Python

Tags: python, postfix-notation, rpn

I am making a Python program where I get an RPN expression separated by spaces and convert it to infix.
It should work like this:

Input RPN: x 2 ^ 3 - 1 2 x * - *

Output : -2x^3 + x^2 + 6x - 3

However, I cannot get it to work with both pronumerals and numbers, for example multiplying it by the pronumeral and again multiplying the entire thing.

Here is my code to compute RPN so far:

```
def getInfix(exp) :
  stack = []
  for i in exp.split(' '):
    if not i in "+-*^" or i.isdigit():
      stack.append(i)
    else:
      stack_one = stack[0]
      stack.pop(0)
      stack_two = stack[0]
      stack.pop(0)
      if str(stack_one).isdigit() and str(stack_two).isdigit():
        stack.insert(0, stack_one + stack_two)
      else:
        stack.insert(0, stack_one + i + stack_two)
      
  return ''.join(stack)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  exp = "x 2 ^ 3 - 1 2 x * - *"
  print(getInfix(exp.strip()))
```

When inputted: x 2 ^ 3 - 1 2 x * - *

Into the exp variable in the main function,

It outputs this:
x^2-3 * 1-2 * x

When it should be outputting this:
-2x^3 + x^2 + 6x - 3

Where am I going wrong with my code?
I have tried doing the same thing with just pronumerals and just numbers and it seems to work...

For reference, I am following the RPN (Shunting Yard) algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm

Comment: There are a number of issues with this. Firstly, you are not distinguishing between unary and binary minus. Secondly, you are identifying operands by checking whether an item is a digit - clearly this won't work for pronumerals. As a first attempt, I suggest you assume that the input is always a valid postfix expression, so that ANYTHING in the input which is not an operator must be an operand. Lastly, you seem to expect the algorithm to not just convert from postfix to infix, but also to collapse certain operations (for example, the 6x in the output, which is not in the input).

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
Yes that's true, I should distinguish and I need a way to collapse the expressions yes...

Comment: How would I actually simplify these expressions?